# Casting to and from Derived Types using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4, casting

I'm somewhat new to using LINQ and Entity Framework, and am running into a snag when casting Entity Framework object types to/from objects of a class derived from that object type.

To provide context, I am selecting `Survey` objects from my Entity Framework DB (records from a `Surveys` table), for which I have created a derived class that I will actually cast these entity objects to before using them in my application - such that the derived class's signature looks something like:

```cs
public sealed class SurveyExtended : Survey
{
    public SurveyExtended() : base()
    {
        // non-base class members initialized here
    }
}
```

And when using LINQ to populate a collection of these objects, I am casting them to the `SurveyExtended` type using code similar to:

```
var listOfSurveyExtendedObjects = ( from record in contextFactory.SurveysDbContext.Surveys  
                                    select new SurveyExtended()
                                               {
                                                  Name = record.Name,
                                                  Data = record.Data,
                                                  Date = record.Date
                                               }
                                  );
```

Please note, I know I could use lambda to do the same thing, but I'm just trying to illustrate a concept.

All is well and good, until I actually try and execute DML against `SurveysDbContext` to do things like `UPDATE` or `DELETE` the original record after processing it in my application, such as: `contextFactory.SurveysDbContext.Surveys.DeleteObject( surveyExtendedObject );`.

Of course this isn't going to work, because I'm manipulating `SurveyExtended` objects, not the original `Survey` entity objects, and the `ObjectStateManager` will throw an `InvalidOperationException` because the object itself cannot be found.  That is to be expected.

I guess what I'm looking for are suggestions and alternative approaches to this scenario.  Should I attempt to cast back to `Survey` objects before trying to `DbContext.DeleteObject( record );`, or change my approach to this problem entirely? In similar situations, what methods did/do you use, and what benefits/drawbacks do they offer?

Comment: Somehow it sounds strange to me that you want to persist an animal but not a dog. Why do you *inherit* a non-entity from an entity?

Comment: Because of additional properties associated with this type of entity that are set/used in my application but aren't stored in the database, and are therefore not associated with the original `Survey` entity object type in its base form.  In regard to your metaphor, I need the `dog` to become a `doberman` in my application because it gains more characteristics that cannot be generalized to just a `dog`. After processing the doberman, need to go back and get rid of the original `dog` record one of two ways depending on whether processing was successful/unsuccessful.

Comment: I would probably prefer composition to associate the additional properties, so `SurveyExtended` contains `Survey` as a member + more properties. Deleting would then be `DeleteObject(surveyExtendedObject.Survey)`. Otherwise, yes, cast it to `Survey` (maybe casting is not enough though, it might be necessary to create a `Survey` and copy the properties over).

Comment: Thanks for your help and input ~ I'll do a little less jumping the gun on inheriting entity objects without realizing the hoops I'll have to jump through to do so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options that come to mind are either cast it back before saving / interacting with EF, or switch to using something like a decorator pattern where the Extended object encapsulates the Survey. Though the second option either means you need to mimic the encapsulated object exposing pass-through accessors (double the code, double the fun) or change referencing code to access `SurveyExtended.Survey.Property`.